# Symfony2 - Full authentication is required to access this resource.

Tags: security, symfony, redirect

I want to redirect anonymous users to the login page, but (obviously) encountered a problem. I get an error:

> Full authentication is required to access this resource.

This is an Internal Server error. I could resolve this by adding the form_login, but I've written a custom auth provider, and using the form_login, would result in the fact that my custom ldap auth provider is not being used anymore. (which means that users cannot login any longer)

```
security:
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false

    login:
      pattern:  ^/login$
      security: false

    api:
      pattern:  ^/api
      security: false

    secured_area:
      pattern:    ^/
      anonymous: true
      ldap: true
      logout:
        path:   /logout
        target: /login

  providers:
    chain_provider:
      chain:
          providers: [in_memory, ldap]
    in_memory:
      memory:
          users:
              admin: { password: adminpass }
    ldap:
      id: ldap_user_provider


  encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    Prophets\ParkingBundle\Entity\User: plaintext

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
    - { path: ^/_wdt, roles: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' }
```

Anyone?

Comment: I'm not sure if this solves your problem but changing the pattern to `^/login/` solved it for me. I found the solution here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Comment: and `firewall: -> dev: -> pattern: ^/`

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but deserves an answer anyway.
I had almost the same issue, but instead of redirecting users I just wanted to display a 403 json page.
The problem is that SF2 does not provide default functionality when there is no `form_login` or that that the default functionality is incomplete, to further research this check out SF2's [ExceptionListener](https://github.com/symfony/security-http/blob/master/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php) class's `handleAccessDeniedException` method.

The workaround the problem is to implement an entry_point on a firewall.
[Security Configuration doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) and a little more about in [Firewalls](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/firewall.html#entry-points).

You just have to implement [Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/EntryPoint/AuthenticationEntryPointInterface.html) interface in a service and point to that service on your entry_point. So I'm assuming you want to **HTTP.302**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\ApiBundle\Security\Firewall;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\AuthenticationEntryPointInterface;

class EntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPointInterface{
  private $url;
  public function __construct($url){
    $this->url = $url;
  }
  public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null){
      $response = new Response(
        '',
        Response::HTTP_FOUND, //for 302 and Response::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT for HTTP307 read about in [Response][4]
        array('Location'=>$this->url)); 
      return $response;
  }
}
```

EDIT: I have to add, this is a known issue and is somewhat design specific/intended error: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8467#issuecomment-163670549

Comment: What is the $url in __construct and how to pass it?

Comment: url is the location to where user gets redirected when not allowed,
This entry point needs to be defined in services.yml where you pass the url parameter to the constructor, and then needs to be called in security.yml on your firewall. please see the links